# Applying force to a dynamically created object

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a problem with trying to apply force to an object after it has been dynamically created.

Let me start by mentioning that I havn't been working in silverlight and with c# for very long and my code is not likely to be very efficient in what it does, but I am trying to make it work.

I have a spaceship that will fire a bullet on keypress. I create this bullet and have it appear a few pixels above the spaceship. Now I want to have it travel across the screen and I just can't get it to work.

```
private void fireShot()
{
    double playerY = 0;
    double playerX = 0;

    PhysicsSprite player = _physicsController.PhysicsObjects["Player"];
    playerX = player.Position.X;
    playerY = player.Position.Y;

    ucStaticPlanet shot = new ucStaticPlanet();
    shot.Name = "shot_" + shotcount;
    shotcount++;

    shot.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Convert.ToDouble(playerX));
    shot.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Convert.ToDouble(playerY - 50));
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(shot);//adds the planet to the canvas
    _physicsController.AddPhysicsBodyForCanvasWithBehaviors(shot.LayoutRoot);
```

The bullet that is created does not move upon creation. It is instead just going to get dragged towards to the ground due to the gravity I have in place. I want the bullet to have some speed as it is created, so as to act like a bullet.

I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I should have made that a bit more clear, I guess. The bullet that is created does not move upon creation. It is instead just going to get dragged towards to the ground due to my gravity. I want the bullet to have some speed as it is created, so as to act like a bullet.

Comment: I guess this happens because you haven't set any velocity to the shot? Is ucStaticPlanet a class of yours? You need to create a PhysicsObject and set some velocity to it.

Comment: That could be it. ucStaticPlanet is a class I believe. It is called static planet because it was used as such in a different project, and I am now just trying stuff out, reusing material. I tried applying a PhysicsObjectBehavior, but none of the properties I can find says anything about altering its veocity. I use something called PhysicsHelper that provides me with a bunch of different things that I can apply to my objects. ApplyForceBehavior is one of those, and the one I would assume I need to use somehow.